# php foreach does not take all values from array

Tags: php, arrays, string, foreach

I'm making a json string which only contains the values which are entered in the form. so far it's going good but the only problem is that the foreach function which makes the string does not take all items from array.

Let's explain something and show my code:
if the $title is not empty I want my final ($content1) string to start with that value. Because it has some other quotes and curlybraces than other values. the same with the date field I also made an if for that because it also contains "date" in it. See my code below:

```
$title = "fiat titel";
$engine = "1.8";
$day = "1";
$month = "2";
$year = "1999";
$dateBuild = "02/02/1999";

// assoc array push function
function array_push_assoc($array, $key, $value){
$array[$key] = $value;
return $array;
}

$array = array();

if(!empty($title)) {
    $array = array_push_assoc($array, 'title', $title);
}

if(!empty($color)) {
    $array = array_push_assoc($array, 'field_modelcolor', $color);
}

if(!empty($model)) {
    $array = array_push_assoc($array, 'field_carmodel', $model);
}

if(!empty($engine)) {
    $array = array_push_assoc($array, 'field_modelengine', $engine);
}

if(!empty($fuel)) {
    $array = array_push_assoc($array, 'field_modelfuel', $fuel);
}

if(!empty($day) && !empty($month) && !empty($year)) {
    $array = array_push_assoc($array, 'field_modelyear', $dateBuild);
}





$content1 = "";

foreach($array as $ftitle => $value) {
    if(empty($content1) && !empty($title)) {
        $content1 = ',"' . $ftitle . '":"' . $value . '"';
    }
    if(!empty($day) && !empty($month) && !empty($year)) {
        $content1 = ',"' . $ftitle . '":{"und":[{"value":{"date":"' . $value . '"}}]}';
    }
    $content1 = ',"' . $ftitle . '":{"und"[{"value":"' . $value . '"}]}';
}

$postContent = '{"type":"carmodels"' . $content1 . '}';

var_dump($array);

echo $postContent;
```

Right now it's only echo'ing:
{"type":"carmodels","field_modelyear":{"und"[{"value":"02/02/1999"}]}}

And it should be (example):
{"type":"carmodels","field_modelyear":{"und":[{"value":{"date":"02/02/1999"}}]},"field_modelengine":{"und"[{"value":"1.6"}]}}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Missing $color, $model variable values..please post full php code

Comment: It makes no difference. There can be anything in that values but it only gives 1 result as output and I need all the entered values

Comment: What’s with that `array_push_assoc` function? Why don’t you just “push” your values directly into the array instead of calling such a function of questionable use?

Comment: And you should not be trying to “build” JSON as a string in the first place. Build a proper data structure that holds your data (array or object), and then use `json_encode` to generate a JSON representation of it.